# Using async/await within a read stream to batch upload to DynamoDB

Tags: javascript, typescript, amazon-dynamodb

A bit of a Node novice here...

I'm trying to write a function that pulls a CSV down from S3 and batch-writes the items to DynamoDB. DynamoDB has a limit of 25 in each batch so I need write the entries as I go. The problem I'm running into is that my `await` function to execute the DB write only fires at the `.end()`, rather than when I check.

I understand that I can't execute things like this, but I'm not sure how to fix it? I'm using Node12.

Thanks.

```js
async function populateTable(
  dataFile: bucketKey,
  tableName: string
): Promise<void> {
  const s3 = getS3Client();
  const stream = s3.getObject(dataFile).createReadStream();

  const BATCH_COUNT = 25; // Max size to write to DynamoDB
  let counter = 0;
  let datarows: any = [];
  let datarow = {};

  stream
    .pipe(parse(DATA_HEADERS))
    .on("data", async function(data: DataRow) {
      counter++;

      datarow = {
        PutRequest: {
          Item: data
        }
      };

      datarows.push(datarow);

      if (counter % BATCH_COUNT === 0) {
        console.log("before batch write " + counter); // This fires!
        await batchWriteToDynamo(datarows, tableName); // I want this function to fully execute before moving on
        console.log("after batch write " + counter); // This does not
        datarows = [];
      }
    })
    .on("end", async function() {
      await batchWriteToDynamo(datarows, tableName); // This fires!
    });
}
```

Comment: Where is the code for `batchWriteToDynamo()`? Also, how many items in total are we talking about here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd guess that these stream events aren't async compatible; you might have to resort to creating your own promise chain. You could potentially do that in the following manner:

```
  let datarow = {};
  let pr = Promise.resolve();
  // ...
      if (counter % BATCH_COUNT === 0) {
        let scopedRows = datarows.slice(); // scoped shallow copy
        pr = pr.then(()=> batchWriteToDynamo(scopedrows, tableName));

  // ...
    .on("end", async function() {
      pr = pr.then(()=> batchWriteToDynamo(datarows, tableName));
```

This should make sure your batch writes happen one at a time and in the correct order. Note also the shallow copy of `datarows` during the data event. Pretty sure this is necessary since events and promises will be happening in an unpredictable order.

But in the end event it shouldn't be necessary since `datarows` shouldn't be changing any more at that point, I would guess.

Comment: Hi David -- Just wanted to confirm that this appears to work and the scopedRows was a necessary addition.

Comment: @David784 can you please tell me little elaborately how you achieved it, got stuck in the same issue